# cpp binary data portability

Tags: c++, binary, 64-bit, portability

Currently, on 32bit machine I write binary data to the file like this:

```
outbin.write( reinterpret_cast <const char *> ( &key_session ), sizeof( unsigned int ) );
outbin.write( reinterpret_cast <const char *> ( &last_access_time ), sizeof( time_t ) );
outbin.write( reinterpret_cast <const char *> ( &sizet ), sizeof( size_t ) );
outbin.write( reinterpret_cast <const char *> ( &ddd), sizeof( double ) );
outbin.write( reinterpret_cast <const char *> ( &fff), sizeof( float ) );
```

How to write data to make it portable and be sure that data will be loaded at any machine (64bit) ? (maybe when operation system will be changed at the machin to 64bit or data wil be copied to other machine)

Comment: Well, different machines may have different sizes for `int`, `size_t`, etc.  So this is going to be tricky.  I would strongly suggest using types like `uint32_t`, etc.

Comment: It's better to write precisely in a document the format (byte order, IEEE754, and so on). So that you don't try to read and write from one native format to another but to and from the specified format. [This](http://commandcenter.blogspot.fr/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html) may be an interesting read. Of course you'll choose your format to be the easiest to read and write in targeted platforms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++0x, use types like `std::uint32_t` from `<cstdint>`. In older compilers, use the C99 header `<stdint.h>`; this is missing from MSVC, but various implementations of it float around the web. You'll have to cast all your `int` and `size_t` variables to `<cstdint>` types when writing and back to native types when reading.

`float` and `double` do not have portable, known-width versions, so you might have to assume that they match single and double formats from IEEE 754. Some assertions might help here.

As for `time_t`, note that it has no standardized meaning across platforms except that it can represent time in some unspecified way.

(Also, keep in mind that you might want to write data out in an endian-neutral format.)

Comment: thanks, all sounds difficult. and a lot of potential losses when porting data. maybe the better way is to write data to special format for import/export operation. and after migration import it.. (eg. xml/txt)

Comment: @abrahab: yes, text files can make this a lot easier, but do keep in mind that a 32-bit program must still do validation on a `size_t` written from a 64-bit program, since it might be too large.

Comment: thanks for you help! I will keep in mind. more often, data upgraded from 32bit -> 64bit :)more